# How does node.js return response to REST web service synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, promise

Excuse me if this is pretty obvious! I am having a tough time trying to understand how does node.js respond to requests from browser. I have gone through tutorials on internet where express.js was used to build the rest server side code with node.js. Now apart from that routes are set up which works on promises. So it is pretty obvious that the response would be sent back only when the promises resolve. So the flow would be -

// 1st line

browser -> REST Service

// 2nd Line

REST Service -> find the route -> hit the service -> get the data -> Send the data back to the browser

The entire process on second line is in asynchronous mode. So will there be a thread hanging at the server end and browser would be waiting for node.js enabled REST service to return response ? If that is not the case, how does the browser or say a REST client such as POSTMAN come to know of the response in real time.

EDIT:

I have removed the external link since it was creating confusion.

Comment: "So will there be a thread hanging at the server end" — Why would there be? As you said, it uses promises.

Comment: "browser would be waiting for node.js enabled REST service to return response" — HTTP clients *always* have to wait for responses. Networking takes time. There's nothing special here.

Comment: If they have to wait for responses, some thread will be open on the server end as well, right ? Otherwise how will you return the response back ?

Comment: @user3276247 not a thread, but a (TCP) connection. A single-threaded process can have many of those open at the same time.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nodejs does not use threads for network requests.  It uses asynchronous support for networking that is built into the operating system.  So, a pending network request in nodejs does not maintain an open thread per request.  It will have an open socket.  The nodejs process will be notified when there is data pending on that socket.

Similarly, promises do not cause a thread to be open.  Promises are simply a notification scheme that an underlying asynchronous operation will resolve or reject when the async operation finishes and then the promises can notify code that has registered `.then()` handlers.

In the link you provided, it is unclear exactly which code you are referring to.  If you want to ask about a specific piece of code there, then please paste that code directly into your question to both make it clear and to follow stack overflow's guidelines about code that you're asking about not being present only in an external link.

> The entire process on second line is in asynchronous mode. So will there be a thread hanging at the server end and browser would be waiting for node.js enabled REST service to return response ?

It's not clear what you mean by "second line".  There's lots of code in the link you provided.  Networking requests inside of nodejs do not use a thread per request.  They keep an open TCP socket, but use the underlying asynchronous notification support in the OS for sockets, not native threads.

> If that is not the case, how does the browser or say a REST client such as POSTMAN come to know of the response in real time.

POSTMAN or the REST client have a TCP connection (using the HTTP protocol on that TCP connection) to the server.  They create the TCP connection, then send an HTTP request on that socket and that socket stays open while they wait for a response.  When the server finishes its business, it sends the response back over the open TCP socket.  There are lots of different ways the client-side code could be written (POSTMAN and the browser likely write their client code differently), but when data arrives on the TCP socket, the client will be notified somehow that there is data to read, the client will read that data, process the response and then since this is an HTTP request/response protocol, the TCP connection will probably be closed.

Comment: External link was just to illsutrate the flow =>

REST Service -> find the route -> hit the service -> get the data -> Send the data back to the browser

I was not referring to any particular piece of code there.

Comment: I have also annotated the 2nd line with the comment. Anyways your answer resolves my query. I will accept it. Thanks for such a detailed response.